# batch rendering several .blend files with the same light setup

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

I was wondering about the easiest way to render multiple objects (like 100 different objects) with the same light setup without creating a light setup in each '.blend' file.

I created a '.blend' for each object, the object is parented to an empty and grouped. On the other hand I created a '.blend' where I have my light setup, camera, compositing, etc.

Is there a way to make all my renders easily?

Thanks for help :) 
Katsele

Comment: Also the same focal length/camera settings? Object sizes?

Comment: Everything the same just the object changes

Comment: Probably the best way is to open your light setup and run a python script that will look for all `.blend` files in given directory, and for each of them: 1. import new object, 2. render, 3. remove current object. I don't know Bledner API yet but it shouldn't be hard. Will try when not on mobile if noone does it.